# Opening process and changing window position

Tags: c#

I want to open from c# an application (standalone flashplayer) and set it position to (0,0) on the screen. How can I do this? So far I've managed to open flashplayer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace swflauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process flash = new Process();
            flash.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            flash.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\development\\flex4\\runtimes\\player\\10\\win\\FlashPlayer.exe";
            flash.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `SetWindowPos` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx). [This](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) page shows how to call it from C#.

Comment: Not a good answer because there is no working code provided. Further, the page showing "how to call it from C#" is a mess _and_ does not actually provide a fully-functioning example (unknown method GetActiveWindowHandle). The lower answer by the author is much better. Concise and functional.

Answer (score 52):

thanks guys, it's working now! :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace swflauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process flash = new Process();
            flash.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            flash.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\development\\flex4\\runtimes\\player\\10\\win\\FlashPlayer.exe";
            flash.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            IntPtr id = flash.MainWindowHandle;
            Console.Write(id);
            Program.MoveWindow(flash.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 500, 500, true);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);


    }
}
```

Comment: Much better than the answer because you actually bothered to share working code, thanks.

Comment: I use a document name instead of an executable name in StartInfo. With Paint and a .jpg argument in StartInfo.FileName this works fine too. But the code does not work with any mime type in FileName. When the mime type is e.g. an image format to be opened with the standard Windows 10 picture viewer "Photos", the program will result in an exception "no process associated with this object" on the MoveWindow call.

Comment: Instead of `Thread.Sleep(100)`, `flash.WaitForInputIdle()` is much better to get `MainWindowHandle`.

Answer (score 7):

Once you start the `Process`, its `MainWindowHandle` property should be set to some Windows handle that can be used for manipulating with the main window of the started application. I don't think there is a way to move it directly using .NET API, but you can use the `MoveWindow` API function via P/Invoke.

Here are some links where you can find more information:

- [`MainWindowHandle` property of `Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=VS.100).aspx) at MSDN
- [`MoveWindow` API function](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.movewindow) at pinvoke.net

Comment: Process.WaitForInputIdle() will be important.