# Application window is not centered in panel (C# forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am trying to embed an application window into my windows form application. For testing purposes, I used notepad. I am embedding it into my panel using the following:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    

        Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);         
    }
```

where

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

The result is that notepad is embedded into my panel, but it is somewhere off to the right. It's not centered such that the top left of notepad aligns with the top left corner of the panel. I am able to drag and move notepad to align it, but I want it done automatically.

I tried playing with the Anchor, Dock, Margin, and Padding settings and nothing really worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032246/c-sharp-opening-process-and-changing-window-position

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are trying to do is completely non-standard, and you have zero guarantees of success.  The application may very well rely on the fact that its window is a topmost, parentless window.

If you insist on experimenting, you need to get the RECT of your panel's client area, and call `SetWindowPos()` on the guest application's window to put it in the right place.

(If that does not work, you might also have to invoke `MapWindowRect()` to map the coordinates. But this should probably not be needed.)