# Run console application from C# with specific window size

Tags: c#, console

I am running a console application from my C# program and I am then redirecting the output to my application. But the length of each line I am receiving seems to be cut to the width the console window is. Can I change the size of that window?

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = psi;

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_ErrorDataReceived;
        process.OutputDataReceived += Proc_OutputDataReceived;

        process.Start();

        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Solution - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032343/2794280](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032343/2794280)

Comment: Thanks, but this is for the window itself and not really for the console content?