# Positioning the FFPlay window on the screen at a specific location

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

My goal is to set the position of the [ffplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html) window to some specific coordinates (e.g. 200 x 400).

Initially, I tried using [ffplay command line arguments](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#toc-Main-options), but I only found how to set window width and height, not position.

Then I tried opening the process in a [specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3032343/18629943) with C#, but this didn't seem to affect the position of FFPlay

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Process proccess = new Process();
        proccess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        proccess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\ffmpeg\\x64\\ffplay.exe";
        proccess.StartInfo.Arguments = "udp://@127.0.0.1:5004?pkt_size=1316";
        proccess.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        IntPtr id = proccess.MainWindowHandle;
        Console.Write(id);
        Program.MoveWindow(proccess.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 500, 500, true);

    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line you can use the options:

```
-left nnn
```

and

```
-top nnn
```

which position the top-left corner of the output - space providing, depending on your screen size.